# How to access the Inner Proprty at the time of new object creation using LINQ C#?

Tags: c#, properties, model, new-operator

I'm having a model class name person

```
public class person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string[] cars { get; set; }
    public int NoOfCars { get; set; }
}
```

I'm having an ObservableCollection namely PersonsList. Now I'm going to initialize the ObservableCollection

```
person pItem = new person
{
    Name = "Sakthi",
    cars = new string[] { "Honda City", "Maruthi Ciaz" },
    NoOfCars = cars.Count()
}

ObservableCollection<person> PersonsList = new ObservableCollection<person>();
PersonsList.Add(pItem);
```

Here I need to assign the **NoOfCars** from the **cars** Property without mentioning manually the value as **2** or by using external string[] variable explicitly. I need the Solution implicitly inline by using LINQ C#

Comment: _"I need the Solution implicitly inline by using LINQ"_ Why that? Apart from the fact that you show only a single object where you LINQ is pointless, why do you need it inline at all?

Comment: If I use (new string[] { "Honda City", "Maruthi Ciaz" }).Count() means it consumes memory unwantedly. That's am asking.

Comment: So why can't you use `2` then? If already the`string[]` is static and not available as variable. Store the `string[]` in a property of an anonymous type. Then you can use it to initialize the object and also to derive the `NoOfCars` value from it. But we have to see your real query to show you how.

Comment: I Just Showcased the Sample Collection. Its a collection querried form another collection not a static assignment as like the above.

Answer (score 3):

You can add the logic to the property itself:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string[] Cars { get; set; }
    public int NoOfCars { get { return Cars == null ? 0 : Cars.Length; } }
}
```

No need to provide a setter.

Side note: you should follow the .NET [Capitalization Conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043(v=vs.110).aspx).

---

If you can't modify the class and you need it inline(why at all?), you can't access other properties from within the object initializer since the object is yet not fully initialized. So it's simply not allowed.

Why can't you store the array in a variable?

```
string[] myCars= { "Honda City", "Maruthi Ciaz" };
person pItem = new person
{
    Name = "Sakthi",
    cars = myCars,
    NoOfCars = myCars.Length
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But my Model class is in Remote Server. I Can't able to modify it or I can't able to create a derived class. Kindly assist me.

Comment: I have to place this assignment in a Complex LINQ. It's a Single Statement Execution. So, I need it in Inline assignment not a explicit assignment using an external variable. Kindly assist me.

Comment: @B.Balamanigandan: Store the `string[]` in a property of an anonymous type. Then you can use it to initialize the object and also to derive the `NoOfCars` value from it. But we have to see your real query to show you how.

Answer (score 1):

Field-initialization is a all-or-nothing-operation. Either all operations or none are executed, however the results of this embracing operations are only visible when *everything* is done. Thus you cannot use `cars.Count()` within the initializer. In particular the `cars`-property does not even *exist* in the scope of your initializer so you can´t access it in any way.

You have to set it after initializing your `Person` either explicitely via `NoOfCars = pItem.cars.Count()` or as Tim already mentioned within the getter of `NoOfCars` itself.

EDIT: If you really want to use field-initialization you may create the array in front and set the `Person` afterwards:

```
var cars = new string[] { "Honda City", "Maruthi Ciaz" };
person pItem = new person
{
    Name = "Sakthi",
    cars = cars,
    NoOfCars = cars.Count()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your model class is remote please try this

```
 person pItem = new person
 {
  Name = "Sakthi",
  cars = new string[] { "Honda City", "Maruthi Ciaz" },
  NoOfCars = 0
 }
```

and before adding the item to list compute the value of **NoOfCars**

```
        ObservableCollection<person> PersonsList = new ObservableCollection<person>();
        pItem.NoOfCars = pItem.cars.Count();
        PersonsList.Add(pItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't modify the Person class, you can write a method (otherwise you could give it a proper constructor):

```
Person CreatePerson(string name, string[] cars) {
    Person p = new Person();
    p.Name = name;
    p.Cars = cars;
    p.NoOfCars = cars.Length;
    return p;
}
```

Then call it:

```
PersonsList.Add(CreatePerson("Sakthi", new string[] { "Honda City", "Maruthi Ciaz" }));
```